# I can't delete a row from datatable primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I know this ask is repeated, but none response help me to solve this problem.
I'm trying to delete a row from a primefaces datatable with a commandButton and a confirmDialog, this doesn't work because the backBean isn't getting the values. When I'm trying to delete this show me a null pointer exception. well see my code if you can help me.

This is my XHTML:

```
<h:form id="principalForm">
        <p:menubar>
            <p:menuitem value="Nuevo" icon="ui-icon-plusthick" oncomplete="PF('wdlgIngresar').show();"/>
        </p:menubar>
        <p:dataTable id="dtpacientes" value="#{beanPersona.listPersona}" var="per"
                     paginator="true" rows="15" rowsPerPageTemplate="15,20,30" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                     paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" 
                     selectionMode="single" selection="#{beanPersona.currPersona}" rowKey="#{per.id}">

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{beanPersona.onRowSelect}" update=":dlgVer" oncomplete="PF('wdlgVer').show()" />

            <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{per.id}" filterBy="#{per.id}">
                <h:outputText value="#{per.id}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Nombre" sortBy="#{per.nombres} #{per.apellidos}" filterBy="#{per.nombres} #{per.apellidos}">
                <h:outputText value="#{per.nombres} #{per.apellidos}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Correo" sortBy="#{per.correo}" filterBy="#{per.correo}">
                <h:outputText value="#{per.correo}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Edad" >
                <h:outputText value="#{beanPersona.getEdad(per.nacimiento)}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Sexo" >
                <h:outputText value="#{beanPersona.getSexo(per.sexo)}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column id="actions" headerText="Acciones">
                <p:commandButton title="Borrar" icon="ui-icon-trash" update=":principalForm:deleteConfirmDialog"
                                 oncomplete="PF('deleteConfirmation').show();" actionListener="#{beanPersona.nullMethod}">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{per}" target="#{beanPersona.currPersona}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <!-- HERE beanPersona.currPersona.id HAVE THE CURRENT VALUE CORRECTLY-->
        <p:confirmDialog id="deleteConfirmDialog" header="Atencion!" severity="alert" widgetVar="deleteConfirmation"
                         message="Desea eliminar paciente Nº #{beanPersona.currPersona.id} ?" >
            <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Sí" oncomplete="PF('deleteConfirmation').hide();"
                             update=":principalForm:dtpacientes" action="#{beanPersona.eliminar(beanPersona.currPersona)}" />
            <p:commandButton id="decline" value="No" oncomplete="PF('deleteConfirmation').hide();"/>
        </p:confirmDialog>
    </h:form>
```

This is my Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BeanPersona implements Serializable {

    private Persona persona = new Persona();
    private Persona currPersona = new Persona();

    public BeanPersona() {
        persona = new Persona();
        currPersona = new Persona();
    }

    public Persona getCurrPersona() {
        return currPersona;
    }

    public void setCurrPersona(Persona currPersona) {
        this.currPersona = currPersona;
    }

    public Persona getPersona() {
        return persona;
    }

    public void setPersona(Persona persona) {
        this.persona = persona;
    }

    public void eliminar(Persona currPersona) {
        if(currPersona != null) {
            new Dml().delete(currPersona, currPersona.getId());
            listar();
            System.out.println("succefull delete !!!!");
        } else if(this.currPersona != null){
            new Dml().delete(this.currPersona, this.currPersona.getId());
            this.currPersona = new Persona();
            listar();
            System.out.println("succefull delete this.currPersona!!!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("currPersona is null !!!!");
        }            
    }

    public String nullMethod () {return null;}

}
```

currPersona still null when I throw the method

Comment: So what scope is the bean? Where's the NPE thrown?

Comment: scope is ViewScooped, see update. And the NPE is throwed when I'm execute the eliminar method, because it says that currPersona is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, I just put process tag into "confirm" commandButton with value at "@this"

```
            <p:column id="actions" headerText="Acciones">
                <p:commandButton title="Borrar" icon="ui-icon-trash" update=":principalForm:deleteConfirmDialog" 
                                 oncomplete="PF('deleteConfirmation').show();" actionListener="#{beanPersona.setCurrPersona(per)}">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{per}" target="#{beanPersona.currPersona}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <!-- HERE beanPersona.currPersona.id HAVE THE CURRENT VALUE CORRECTLY-->
        <p:confirmDialog id="deleteConfirmDialog" header="Atencion!" severity="alert" widgetVar="deleteConfirmation"
                         message="Desea eliminar a paciente Nº #{beanPersona.currPersona.id} ?" closeOnEscape="true" >
            <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Sí" oncomplete="PF('deleteConfirmation').hide();"
                             update=":principalForm:dtpacientes" action="#{beanPersona.eliminar}" process="@this"/>
            <p:commandButton id="decline" value="No" oncomplete="PF('deleteConfirmation').hide();"/>
        </p:confirmDialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `onclick` is for client side behaviour like executing some JS or showing up a dialog etc. You are not defining an actionListener for your commandButton at all.

Try to remove the `onclick` completely and use a proper actionListener instead:

```
<p:column id="actions" headerText="Acciones">
    <p:commandButton title="Borrar" icon="ui-icon-trash" 
        update=":principalForm:deleteConfirmDialog"
        oncomplete="PF('deleteConfirmation').show();"
        actionListener="#{beanPersona.someActionListener}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{per}" 
                    target="#{beanPersona.currPersona}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

Comment: because the action listener is after, in the confirmDialog, the commandButton only shows that confirmDialog and set the value to currPersona with the f:setPropertyActionListener

Comment: You have to send *two* requests. One to set your value `currPersona` and later in your dialog another one to perform the delete action. For the first actionListener you may call a 'dummy' that does nothing like `public String someActionListener(){ return null }`. Maybe an ugly hack, but it works.

Comment: I did what you said but still not working. I made a method that does not perform any action, also try to pass the value in changing the onclick to actionListener but nothing.